# Ember model hooking with data received as JSON with REST

Tags: javascript, json, django, rest, ember.js

I'm really new to ember and I'm trying to send a JSON data with my REST backend (I'm using Django REST framework with Django JSON API), but I'm getting some weird errors.

**FIREFOX**

Error:

```
Error while processing route: sampledata.index data is null _pushInternalModel@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76923:11 push@http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76900:31
```

and a Warning:

```
WARNING: Encountered a resource object with type "sampledata", but no model was found for model name "sampledatum" (resolved model name using 'frontend@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("sampledata")).
```

**CHROME**

Error:

```
Error while processing route: sampledata.index Cannot read property 'type' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
at Class._pushInternalModel (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76923:27)
at Class.push (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:76900:36)
at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:77627:15
at Object.run (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:10805:25)
at Class._adapterRun (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:77149:31)
at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:77624:13
at tryCatch (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63933:14)
at invokeCallback (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63948:15)
at publish (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:63916:9)
at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:42181:7logError @ ember.debug.js:28535error @ ember.debug.js:28478triggerEvent @ ember.debug.js:28594trigger @ ember.debug.js:53473trigger @ ember.debug.js:53287(anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:53107tryCatch @ ember.debug.js:53806invokeCallback @ ember.debug.js:53821publish @ ember.debug.js:53789publishRejection @ ember.debug.js:53724(anonymous function) @ ember.debug.js:32054invoke @ ember.debug.js:333flush @ ember.debug.js:397flush @ ember.debug.js:205end @ ember.debug.js:560run @ ember.debug.js:682join @ ember.debug.js:702run.join @ ember.debug.js:21181hash.success @ rest.js:910fire @ jquery.js:3187fireWith @ jquery.js:3317done @ jquery.js:8757(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:9123
other error.. TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
```

My data sent is:

```
{
    "links": {
        "first": "http://localhost:8000/api/sampledata?page=1",
        "last": "http://localhost:8000/api/sampledata?page=1",
        "next": null,
        "prev": null
    },
    "data": [{
        "type": "sampledata",
        "id": "4",
        "attributes": {
            "blind_id": "1-146788",
            "aliquots_circulation": 9,
            "total_dna": 120,
            "data_type": "WES"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "projects": {
                "data": [],
                "meta": {
                    "count": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pages": 1,
            "count": 1
        }
    }
}
```

My ember model (/app/models/sampledata.js):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  blind_ID: DS.attr('string'),
  aliquotsCirculation: DS.attr('number'),
  totalDna: DS.attr('number'),
  dataType: DS.attr('string'),
  projects: DS.hasMany('project')
});
```

My adapter (/app/adapters/application.js):

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ENV from 'frontend/config/environment';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  host: ENV.host,
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

My serializer (/app/serializers/application.js)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

});
```

If I change my serializer to

```
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id',
  serializeId: function(id) {
    return id.toString();
  }
});
```

I get the following **WARNINGS** and NO ERRORS, but no data is shown:

```
WARNING: Encountered "links" in payload, but no model was found for model name "link" (resolved model name using frontend@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("links"))
vendor.js (line 16826)
WARNING: Encountered "data" in payload, but no model was found for model name "datum" (resolved model name using frontend@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("data"))
```

Comment: Are you sure that nowhere in your response you typed `sampledatum` instead of `sampledata`?

Comment: Yes. I went over the code anyway and rechecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after hours I figured it out.

Ember has this thing called Inflector and it was pluralizing my word "data" to "datum". That's why it was not finding my model and that's why changing my model to sample-data.js as suggested did not work.

Reference here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_pluralization-customization

Two solutions:

1) Rename the model and templates. Model should be singular, templates in plural

2) Use Ember.Inflector
(/app.js)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export function initialize(/* container, application */) {
  var inflector = Ember.Inflector.inflector;
  inflector.uncountable('sampledata');
}

export default {
  name: 'inflector',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo. You extend adapter instead serializer.

```
//(/app/serializers/application.js)

    import DS from 'ember-data';

    export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

    });
```

To resolve warning

```
WARNING: Encountered a resource object with type "sampledata", but no model was found for model name "sampledatum" (resolved model name using 'frontend@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("sampledata")).
```

overwrite in serializer like this :

```
modelNameFromPayloadType(type){
  if(type === 'sampledata') return type;
  return this._super(...arguments);
}
```

Comment: It gives other errors when I fix the typo which was giving before I posted here. I've been playing this for a while... and I got confused at some point. I updated the error. It gives a warning along the error

Comment: The warning is still showing up (and the error). Google chrome debugger says something more usefull for the error: ember.debug.js:28535 Error while processing route: sampledata.index Cannot read property 'type' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null

Comment: @MarcusRenno I think this is related to model name you choose. I mean `sampledata` and `sampledata.js` model file. Please change the file name to `sample-data.js` and in that function (`modelNameFromPayloadType`) return 'SampleData'

Comment: Change the models/sampledata.js to models/sample-data.js? I changed that and now it is complaining that it cannot find the model sampledata. "Error while processing route: sampledata.index No model was found for 'sampledata' "

Comment: @MarcusRenno Yes. I think you need to follow correct naming. Ember is conventional. After changing model name you need to correct route names too. Also in `modelNameFromPayloadType` you should return correct model name with new model name

Comment: I changed the folder of the route which was 'sampledata' to 'sample-data'. No errors or warnings anymore which is great. Unfortunately now it is not making the GET request anymore to pull the data. I dont understand why I couldnt use sampledata. It does not look like a reserved word or anything like that... in `modelNameFromPayloadType` I changed return type to return 'SampleData'. Nothing happened. I also tried return 'sample-data'...